# split column values into rows and create a unique record for each id

Tags: sql-server

my table is like:

```
id  name        question            answer      comment
1    ann        are you happy?      yes         yes, i am happy.
1    ann        got job?            no          not yet
2    joe        are you happy?      no          sometimes.
2    joe        got job?            no          not yet
3    jim        are you happy?      yes                  
3    jim        got job?            yes         not yet
```

and i want to convert the table like:

```
id  name    question1       answr1  comment1            question2   answer2 comment2
1   ann     are you happy?  yes     yes,i   am  happy.  got job?    no      not yet
2   joe     are you happy?  no      sometimes.          got job?    no      not yet
3   jim     are you happy?  yes                         got job?    yes
```

Comment: Are there always exactly two questions for each name?

Comment: YES, question doe not change. @Shnugo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do I have to tell you, that your table's design is bad? This is breaking the rules of normalisation...

Best was to repair this

- a separate table for your people
- a related table for questions

If you've got standard questions you might introduce an own table for this and link them within a `n:m` related mapping table.

For your actual situation there's *conditional aggregation* to your rescue:

```
DECLARE @mockupTable TABLE(id INT,name VARCHAR(100),question VARCHAR(100),answer VARCHAR(100),comment VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @mockupTable VALUES
 (1,'ann','are you happy?','yes','yes, i am happy.')
,(1,'ann','got job?','no','not yet')
,(2,'joe','are you happy?','no','sometimes.')
,(2,'joe','got job?','no','not yet')
,(3,'jim','are you happy?','yes','')
,(3,'jim','got job?','yes','not yet');

WITH NumberedRows AS
(
    SELECT t.*
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS RowNr
    FROM @mockupTable AS t
)
SELECT id,name

      ,MAX(CASE WHEN RowNr = 1 THEN question END) AS question1
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN RowNr = 1 THEN answer END) AS answer1
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN RowNr = 1 THEN comment END) AS comment1

      ,MAX(CASE WHEN RowNr = 2 THEN question END) AS question2
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN RowNr = 2 THEN answer END) AS answer2
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN RowNr = 2 THEN comment END) AS comment2

FROM NumberedRows 
GROUP BY id,name;
```